# accessing values in string

Tags: python

i just started python after php and javascript but i am confused in this easy concept....i already search a lot about this on tutorialpoints or w3school but i find nothing

here is the example code

```
var1 = 'Hello-World!'
print("var1[:6]: ", var1[:6])
```

This code will print the output as 
**Hello-**
but here where is the W word because a string always start from 0 value so w will also be printed .....

anyways now i decided to print every word seperately

```
print("var1[0]: ", var1[0])
print("var1[1]: ", var1[1])
print("var1[2]: ", var1[2])
print("var1[3]: ", var1[3])
print("var1[4]: ", var1[4])
print("var1[5]: ", var1[5])
print("var1[6]: ", var1[6])
```

and the output is

```
var1[0]:  H
var1[0]:  e
var1[0]:  l
var1[0]:  l
var1[0]:  o
var1[0]:  -
var1[0]:  W
```

now i am really confused that why W is not printed in my first example code ?

Comment: `[x:y]` is slicing syntax of python. `[x]` refers to indexing.

Comment: and in my first example i am not defined the x value that means it must start from 0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

List slicing goes from the first index *until* the last index. In other words, the slice

```
var1[0:6]  # same as var1[:6]
```

covers the indices 0 through 5, but not 6.

The reason `W` is not printed is because `W` is index 6. If you want to include `W`, then you need to do `var1[0:7]`.

This is intuitive, because if you do, say, `var1[m:n]`, then you get a substring of exactly `m - n` length. Similarly, if I say I want `var1[:6]`, I'm saying I want the first `6` characters of `var1`. Not the seventh character, which would have index 6.

Comment: that means that it will print all value before 6th position by ignoring 6th position letter?

Comment: It might be useful to conceptualize that the *first* element of the list has index *0*, the *second* has index *1*, etc. So the 6th element has index 5, and the 7th element (that is, `'W'`) has index 6.

Comment: bro 6th element is w

Comment: 0  = H , 1 = e, 2 = l, 3 = l, 4 = 0, 5 = -, 6 = w

Comment: The first element has index `0`, so `w` is the seventh element with index `6`.